# how to find the minimum product of two rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: I want to find the minimum of the products of each number with the number next to it]

[image]

How do I find the minimum of all the products of each number in each row?
For example here, the minimum would be 2 because 2x1 = 2 is less than 6x1 = 6 and so on. I could do this by making a separate column of all the multiples and find the minimum of that, but I don't want to unnecessarily make another column.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to find the minimum value of the product of Column A and B.

**Try:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(FILTER(A2:A12,A2:A12>0)*FILTER(B2:B12,B2:B12>0)))
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Explanation:**

To explain simply you just need to use multiply the columns and use the `MIN()` function with `ArrayFormula()` like this `=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(A2:A12*B2:B12))`, but this will return 0 if there are blank rows in the range since it is the minimum value. So you have to use `FILTER()` to both columns to exclude the blank rows and 0 values first before you multiply them.

**Take note:** Both the columns have to be equal size otherwise it would throw an error.

Comment: I know it's bad form to critique another's answer, but you do get 'Array arguments to MULTIPLY are of different size' if there is a blank in one column but not the other.

Comment: I would suggest =ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(FILTER(A2:A12*B2:B12,A2:A12<>"",B2:B12<>""))) but maybe I should stop putting my oar in as answer has been accepted and upvoted!

Comment: @TomSharpe  It's not bad form. It's good to point out flaws for mutual benefit. I usually upvote answers with good explanations. Your answer has lot of words, but most of it can be taken out. For eg, `This would be one approach` adds nothing. So is `try this` or `try` or `doesn't work`. I can understand the code ofcourse, but explanations like: ```Query can be used to multiply arrays and remove blanks, but it is throwing a error when a aggregation function like `min` is used on the product. Hence the need for two queries``` will greatly improve the long term quality of the answer.

Comment: Agree. Part of the problem was the original answer was done in haste (always a bad idea) with no time for embellishment. I do hate code only answers although sometimes guilty of it myself.

Comment: @TomSharpe thanks for the feedback. I have missed pointing out that both the columns have to be equal size otherwise it would throw an error. I have not tested your suggested formula but I will edit my answer to point out the limitation of my posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Query can be used to multiply arrays and remove blanks, but it is throwing a error when an aggregation function like `min` is used on the product:

*=query(C1:D,"select min(C*D) where C is not null and D is not null ",1)*

[image]

Hence the need for two nested queries as follows:

```
=query(query(C1:D,"select C*D where C is not null and D is not null ",1),"select min(Col1)")
```

Note that this deals correctly with the case where a value is missing from one column but not both

[image]